# FTP in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, ftp

I am trying to set up FTP on my Windows Server 2008 machine and have a question. In Role Services, instead of "FTP Server" I have "FTP Publishing Service". What is the difference between the two and how can I install FTP Server on my machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Stop. It's 2012. Don't use FTP.

Comment: @MDMarra: While I could in principle agree, there can be lots of perfectly valid reasons to need a FTP server. Or even worse protocols. Just think about what the infinitely more awful TFTP means for Cisco devices...

Comment: I'm in yer networx, reading yer passwordz. And TFTP's generally read-only, not read-write.

Comment: @AdrianK, I'd downvote your comment because your spelling was too accurate, detracting from the humor :P

Comment: Touche! Outed by my Catholic secondary education. What a sorry life I lead.

Answer (score 6):

That is the FTP server service for Windows Server 2008.  Install that role service to begin setting up your server as an FTP server.

Answer (score 4):

"FTP Publishing Service" is simply the new name of the service in Windows Server 2008; it's exactly the same thing.